# Good resources for learning how to use the Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am starting a new module on a project and hear the Entity Framework 4.0 is coming along nicely with its POCO support, lazy-loading, and many other great features. The problem I have is trying to find good resources for learning the technology that isn't geared towards version 1.0 I am following Julie Lermans blog where she is working on a 2nd edition to her book, but need to find something now with a lot of in-depth code samples and tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: This can be migrated to https://history.stackexchange.com/ now ;) Anyway, it's off-topic by the current site standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at following. Will give you enough exposure about **Entity Framework 4.0**

- **[Entity Framework 4.0: How to use
  POCOs](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/entity-framework-4-0-how-to-use-pocos)**
- **[ADO.NET team blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209012807/http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/default.aspx)**
- **[New Features in Entity Framework 4.0
  (V2)](https://aleembawany.com/2009/05/17/new-features-in-entity-framework-40-v2/)**
- **[The ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/)**
- **[What’s New in Entity Framework
  4 ?](https://web.archive.org/web/20221004110500/https://www.codemag.com/article/0909081)**
- **[Learning resources for Entity
  Framework 4.0 new features](https://bogdanbrinzarea.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/learning-resources-for-entity-framework-4-0-new-features/)**
- **[Model-First Development with the
  Entity Framework 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20211115010804/https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-15-Model-First-Development-with-the-Entity-Framework-40)**
- **[Whats New In Entity Framework 4](https://www.slideshare.net/KulveerSingh/whats-new-in-entity-framework-4)**
- **[Agile Entity Framework 4
  Repository](https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-1-model-and-poco-classes/)**
- **[Creating a Generic Entity Framework
  4.0 Repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025102958/http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx)**
- **[Entity Framework 4.0 Features](http://refact.blogspot.com/2009/09/entity-framework-40-features.html)**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice starter level videos  in [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/) It may help to find more if you try a search in the same web site.